# Style issues with web page, works in firefox, not in ie or chrome

Tags: html, css

I am very inexperienced when it comes to recent html and other languages, I had a little schooling years ago, but that's about it.  I had a friend ask for hep designing a simple web page for him.  I have all the kinks worked out except for on a gallery page I created in the website.  This page seems to work well in firefox, but not on chrome or is.  In ie, it seems to ignore the css sheet altogether.  In chrome, I cannot get the "Preview" image to load.

HTML of Gallery page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
    background: #222;
    margin-top: 20px;
    }
     
    h3 {
    color: #eee;
    font-family: Verdana;
    }
     
    .thumbnails img {
    height: 80px;
        padding: 1px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    }
     
    .thumbnails img:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    }
     
    .preview {
    padding: 1px;
    display: block;
    max-width:500px;
    max-height:399px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    }

#content, html, body {
    height: 98%;
}

#left {
max-height:400px;
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    background: white;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#right {
max-height:400px;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background: white;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

    </style>

   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Gallery - Urban Outdoor Design</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 

href="css/style.css">
   </head>
   <body height: 1000px>

      <div id="page">
         <div id="header">
            <a href="index.html" id="logo"><img 

src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a 

href="services.html">Services</a>
               </li>
               <li class="current">
                  <a 

href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="billpay.html">Bill 

Pay</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a 

href="contact.html">Contact</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div id="body">
            <div id="content">
               <h1>Some Samples of our work:</h1>

               <br>Use the scrollbar at the right 

to browse images, point to an image to view a 

larger version on the left.
              
            </div>


     <div class="gallery" align="center">

<div id="content">
  <div id="left"><img 
    id="preview"
    class="preview"
   
></div>
    <div id="right">
    <div class="thumbnails" align="center">
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=this.src" 

src="gallery/image1.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=this.src" 

src="gallery/image2.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=this.src" 

src="gallery/image3.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=this.src" 

src="gallery/image4.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=this.src" 

src="gallery/image5.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=this.src" 
    
<br>
</div>
    </div>
         </div>
          <div id="footer">
            
            <p>   
               Urban Outdoor Design, LLC &copy; 

2015  | All Rights Reserved
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS sheet:

```css
body {
  background: url(../images/bg-body.jpg) repeat;
  color: #A7A238;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 940px;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  outline: none;
}
img {
  border: 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: justify;
}
p a {
  color: #356618;
}
p a:hover {
  color: #66a143;
}
#page {
  background: #840D22;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 900px;
}
#header {
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 151px;
}
#header a#logo {
  display: block;
  height: 86px;
  padding: 15px 0 0 20px;
}
#header a#logo img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header > ul {
  background: #4b4b4b;
  height: 49px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 900px;
}
#header > ul > li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}
#header > ul > li > a {
  color: #f0f2c9;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  line-height: 49px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#header > ul > li.current > a,
#header > ul > li.current > a:hover,
#header ul li ul li.current a,
#header ul li ul li.current a:hover {
  background: #840d22;
  color: #f0f2c9;
}
#header ul li a:hover {
  background: #daead0;
  color: #1b330c;
}
#header ul li ul {
  list-style: none;
  left: -99999px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 11px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 49px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 2;
}
#header ul li:hover ul {
  left: 0;
  top: 49px;
}
#header ul li ul li {
  background: #4B4B4B;
}
#header ul li ul li a {
  color: #f0f2c9;
  display: block;
  line-height: 31px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#body {
  background: #ffffff;
}
#body div.header {
  height: 410px;
}
#body div.header div {
  position: relative;
}
#body div.header div a img,
#body div.header ul li a.figure img,
#body div.body ul li a img {
  display: block;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  /* Needed for IE8 and old versions */
  opacity: 1;
}
#body div.header div a img:hover,
#body div.header ul li a.figure img:hover,
#body div.body ul li a img:hover {
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  /* Needed for IE8 and old versions */
  opacity: 0.9;
}
#body div.header div div {
  background: url(../images/bg-description.png) repeat-x;
  height: 75px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 17px 20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 860px;
}
#body div.header div div h1 {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#body div.header div div h1 a {
  color: #e3e699;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#body div.header div div h1 a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#body div.header div div p {
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 0.028em;
  line-height: 24px;
}
#body div.header div div p a.continue {
  background: url(../images/interface.png) no-repeat -400px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  left: 3px;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  width: 20px;
}
#body div.header div div p a.continue:hover {
  background: url(../images/interface.png) no-repeat -400px -20px;
}
#body div.header ul {
  background: #356618;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
#body div.header ul li {
  background: url(../images/separator1.png) repeat-y;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 9px 20px 7px 0;
  width: 280px;
}
#body div.header ul li:first-child {
  background: none;
}
#body div#content ul.section li img,
#body div.header ul li a.figure {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
#body div.header ul li a.figure img {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  margin: 0 20px 0;
}
#body div.header ul li.current h3 a {
  color: #e3e699;
}
#body div.header ul li h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 0.028em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 10px;
}
#body div.header ul li h3 a {
  color: #e3e699;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#body div.header ul li h3 a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#body div.header ul li p {
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 0.022em;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: left;
}
#body div.body {
  padding: 23px 20px 0;
}
#body div.body h1,
#body div.footer div h1 {
  background: #dce9d4;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #b3cca4;
  color: #836145;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 37px;
  line-height: 37px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
}
#body div.body ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 21px 0;
}
#body div.body ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  width: 200px;
}
#body div.body ul li:first-child,
#body div#content ul.section li:first-child,
#body div#content div#sidebar div ul li:first-child {
  margin: 0;
}
#body div.body ul li h2 {
  color: #836145;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 24px 0 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#body div.body ul li p {
  color: #4b4b4b;
  letter-spacing: 0.028em;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: left;
}
#body div.footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #d7d6cd;
  margin: 0 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 23px 0;
}
#body div.footer img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
#body div.footer div {
  float: right;
  width: 540px;
}
#body div.footer div ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
#body div.footer div ol li {
  color: #4b4b4b;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
#body div.footer div ol li p {
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.028em;
  line-height: 24px;
}
#body div#content {
  border-top: 1px solid #5d8546;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 35px 20px;
}
#body div#content h1 {
  color: #818181;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.028em;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#body div#content h3 {
  color: #836145;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.028em;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 0 0;
}
#body div#content h3.first {
  padding: 12px 0 0;
}
#body div#content p {
  letter-spacing: 0.028em;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 25px 0 0;
}
#body div#content ul.section {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 29px 0 0;
}
#body div#content ul.section li {
  margin: 35px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#body div#content ul.section li span {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
#body div#content ul.section li div {
  float: right;
  width: 520px;
}
#body div#content ul.section li div h2,
#body div#content div#article h2 {
  color: #836145;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.028em;
  line-height: 13px;
  margin: 0;
}
#body div#content ul.section li div p {
  padding: 23px 0 0;
}
#body div#content form {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 0 0;
}
#body div#content form p {
  color: #818181;
  padding: 0 0 25px;
}
#body div#content form label {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#body div#content form label span:first-child {
  background: none;
  color: #836145;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 200px;
}
#body div#content form label span {
  background: url(../images/interface.png) no-repeat;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 19px;
  width: 320px;
}
#body div#content form label span input {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #818181;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 17px;
  letter-spacing: 0.028em;
  line-height: 17px;
  margin: 1px 0 0 2px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 316px;
}
#body div#content form label span.message {
  background: url(../images/interface.png) no-repeat 0 -25px;
  height: 151px;
}
#body div#content form label span.message textarea {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #818181;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 147px;
  letter-spacing: 0.028em;
  margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0;
  resize: none;
  width: 316px;
}
#body div#content form input#send {
  background: url(../images/interface.png) no-repeat -331px -56px;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 0.028em;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0 0 0 440px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #514b61;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 80px;
}
#body div#content form input#send:hover {
  background: url(../images/interface.png) no-repeat -331px -81px;
}
#body div#content div#article {
  border-right: 1px solid #96b285;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px 0 0;
  width: 580px;
}
#body div#content div#article img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 35px;
}
#body div#content div#article h1 {
  padding: 0 0 17px;
}
#body div#content div#article h2 {
  line-height: 24px;
}
#body div#content div#article span {
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 0.028em;
  line-height: 24px;
}
#body div#content div#sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 242px;
}
#body div#content div#sidebar h3 {
  color: #818181;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: normal;
  padding: 0 0 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#body div#content div#sidebar div {
  border-top: 1px solid #96b285;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
#body div#content div#sidebar div:first-child {
  border: none;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
}
#body div#content div#sidebar div ul,
#footer div div ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#body div#content div#sidebar div ul li {
  color: #818181;
  letter-spacing: 0.028em;
  line-height: 24px;
}
#body div#content div#sidebar div ul li a {
  color: #818181;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#body div#content div#sidebar div ul li a:hover {
  color: #4b4b4f;
}
#body div#content div#sidebar div:first-child ul li {
  letter-spacing: 0.024em;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 15px 0 0;
}
#body div#content div#sidebar div p {
  color: #818181;
  padding: 0;
}
#footer {
  background: #dce9d4;
  border-top: 1px solid #b8d0aa;
}
#footer div {
  height: 174px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#footer div div {
  border-left: 1px solid #b8d0aa;
  float: left;
  height: 134px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  width: 180px;
}
#footer div div:first-child {
  border: none;
}
#footer div div h1 {
  color: #8c8c8c;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 13px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#footer div div ul li a {
  letter-spacing: 0.028em;
  line-height: 18px;
}
#footer div div a {
  color: #8c8c8c;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#footer div div a:hover {
  color: #4b4b4f;
}
#footer div div a#mail {
  background: url(../images/icons.png) no-repeat;
  height: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}
#footer div div a#facebook {
  background: url(../images/icons.png) no-repeat 0 -38px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}
#footer div div a#twitter {
  background: url(../images/icons.png) no-repeat 0 -88px;
  height: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}
#footer div div a#googleplus {
  background: url(../images/icons.png) no-repeat 0 -134px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}
#footer div div a#mail:hover {
  background: url(../images/icons.png) no-repeat 0 -14px;
}
#footer div div a#facebook:hover {
  background: url(../images/icons.png) no-repeat 0 -58px;
}
#footer div div a#twitter:hover {
  background: url(../images/icons.png) no-repeat 0 -106px;
}
#footer div div a#googleplus:hover {
  background: url(../images/icons.png) no-repeat 0 -154px;
}
#footer p {
  background: #840D22;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 37px;
  line-height: 37px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #8da181;
}
```

Here is a link to a screenshot of what it should look like.  It works in Firefox.  On mouseover of a thumbnail on right, it opens a large version of the image in the white space in the body.

http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-2876-171.html

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Try moving the <style> section inside the <head> section.

Comment: Style seems to work for me in chrome, could you provide a screenshot of how it is meant to look. Also whats up with the <style></style> outside of the <head></head>

Comment: I'm fairly new to working in css, and I put the style in the wrong place.  After moving it into head, it produces the same error in chrome (preview image does not populate).  In addition,  the background image for the page (from the css sheet) is now missing and displays a flat black color.

Comment: I have no capability to post images, I do not have enough rep, will post it elsewhere, give me a moment.

Comment: Edited post to include a link at the end with requested screenshot.

Comment: Here as a jfiddle link - so its easyer to take a look http://jsfiddle.net/es92taqz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this for your mouseover will make it work in firefox and chrome

```
onmouseover="document.getElementById('preview').src=this.src"
```

from what I can find it looks like firefox can apply id variables to javascript in this case `preview` will be automatically given an id, while chrome does not do this.

---

Edit:

replace your onmouseover

```
<img onmouseover="preview.src=this.src" src="gallery/image1.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
```

change to

```
 <img onmouseover="document.getElementById('preview').src=this.src" src="gallery/image1.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
```

---

edit 2:

to get the first image already in the area just add a `src=""` to the `<img />` inside of the left div, see below:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="left">
    <img id="preview" class="preview" src="http://d.ibtimes.co.uk/en/full/1409516/how-update-nexus-5-official-android-5-0-lollipop-build-lrx21o-via-factory-image.jpg">
   </div>
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but where would I add that?

Comment: That worked great.  It works in both ie and chrome now.  Thank a lot!

Comment: One final question for those lurking.  Is there a way to get the preview to load an image prior to mouseover?  I would like it to automatically load the first image in the gallery, then change on mouseover.

Comment: I updated again with your other question about the img being auto loaded